# Select the customer who has the most different categories in his orders

Tags: sql, oracle

The question I need to answer is the following: Find the customer(or customers in case of tie),who has done the order which cointains the most different categories.

These are my tables:

Products:

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
PROD_ID NUMBER NOT NULL ,
"CATEGORY" NUMBER NOT NULL REFERENCES Categories,
TITLE VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
ACTOR VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
PRICE VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PROD_ID));
```

OrderLines:

```
CREATE TABLE Orderlines (
ORDERLINEID NUMBER NOT NULL,
ORDERID NUMBER NOT NULL REFERENCES Orders,
PROD_ID NUMBER NOT NULL REFERENCES Products,
QUANTITY NUMBER NOT NULL,
ORDERDATE VARCHAR2 (80) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ORDERLINEID,ORDERID));
```

Customers:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
CUSTOMERID NUMBER NOT NULL,
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
LASTNAME VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
ADDRESS1 VARCHAR2 (40) NOT NULL,
ADDRESS2 VARCHAR2 (40),
CITY VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
STATE VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
ZIP VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
COUNTRY VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
REGION VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
EMAIL VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
PHONE VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
CREDITCARDTYPE VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
CREDITCARD VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
CREDITCARDEXPIRATION VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
USERNAME VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
"PASSWORD" VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
AGE NUMBER NOT NULL,
INCOME NUMBER NOT NULL,
GENDER VARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMERID));
```

Orders:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
ORDERID NUMBER NOT NULL,
ORDERDATE DATE NOT NULL,
CUSTOMERID NUMBER NOT NULL REFERENCES Customers,
NETAMOUNT NUMBER NOT NULL,
TAX NUMBER NOT NULL,
TOTALAMOUNT NUMBER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ORDERID));
```

Comment: Is your  question for mysql or for sql server?

Comment: I'm sorry,it's for oracle

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Comment: For customer with the most categories

select prod_id,agorastes from (
select  p.prod_id,count(distinct ord.customerid) as agorastes
from products p inner join orderlines o on p.prod_id=o.prod_id
inner join orders ord on ord.orderid=o.orderid
group by p.prod_id)t1 inner join (
select max(agor) as megistos   from (
select  p.prod_id,count(distinct ord.customerid) as agor
from products p inner join orderlines o on p.prod_id=o.prod_id
inner join orders ord on ord.orderid=o.orderid
group by p.prod_id))t2 on megistos=agorastes;

Comment: For customer with the least categories

select prod_id,agorastes from (
select  p.prod_id,count(distinct ord.customerid) as agorastes
from products p inner join orderlines o on p.prod_id=o.prod_id
inner join orders ord on ord.orderid=o.orderid
group by p.prod_id)t1 inner join (
select min(agor) as elaxistos   from (
select  p.prod_id,count(distinct ord.customerid) as agor
from products p inner join orderlines o on p.prod_id=o.prod_id
inner join orders ord on ord.orderid=o.orderid
group by p.prod_id))t2 on elaxistos=agorastes;
Chat Conversation End

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Select * from
(
Select C.CUSTOMERID, C.FIRSTNAME , C.LASTNAME, count(distinct P."CATEGORY") as Categories
from Customers C
inner join Orders O on O.CUSTOMERID =C.CUSTOMERID
inner join OrderLines OL on O.ORDERID =OL.ORDERID 
inner join Products P on P.PROD_ID =OL.PROD_ID 
group by C.CUSTOMERID, C.FIRSTNAME , C.LASTNAME
Order by count(P."CATEGORY") desc)A
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Comment: This query doesn't look correct - at first glance, it simply counts the existence of categories as opposed to the number of different categories.

Comment: I added distinct to count only distinct categories.